# doParallel in R cannot open H5File objects

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I'm trying to run a for loop with doParallel but it's not processing my .h5 files.
The code works with `foreach` ... `%do%` but when I parallelize with `%dopar%`, it thrown an error.
Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Here's the regular code that works and gives the output I want:

```
files <- list.files("E:/Protein Data/OneDrive_1_6-18-2021/sample/", 
                    full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".h5")

vector1 <- numeric()
vector2 <- numeric()


system.time({

foreach (i = 1:7) %do% {
  
  data_i <- H5File$new(files[i],'r+')
  object_i <- data_i[["d1"]]
  object_i <- readDataSet(object_i)
  
  
  foreach (j = 1:7) %do% {
    
    data_j <- H5File$new(files[j],'r+')
    object_j <- data_j[["d1"]]
    object_j <- readDataSet(object_j)
    
    vector1[j] <- come calculation
    vector2[j] <- some calculation
    

  }
  
  write.table(vector1, file = paste0("folder1/",paste0(i,"_vec1.txt")), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  write.table(vector2, file = paste0("folder2/",paste0(i,"_vec2.txt")), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  
}

})
```

But this code throws an error:

```
files <- list.files("E:/Protein Data/OneDrive_1_6-18-2021/sample/", 
                    full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".h5")

vector1 <- numeric()
vector2 <- numeric()
numCores <- detectCores()
registerDoParallel(numCores)


system.time({

foreach (i = 1:7) %dopar% {
  
  data_i <- H5File$new(files[i],'r+')
  object_i <- data_i[["d1"]]
  object_i <- readDataSet(object_i)
  
  
  foreach (j = 1:7) %dopar% {
    
    data_j <- H5File$new(files[j],'r+')
    object_j <- data_j[["d1"]]
    object_j <- readDataSet(object_j)
    
    vector1[j] <- some calculation
    vector2[j] <- some calculation
    

  }
  
  write.table(vector1, file = paste0("folder1/",paste0(i,"_vec1.txt")), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  write.table(vector2, file = paste0("folder2/",paste0(i,"_vec2.txt")), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  
}

})
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image]

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'H5File' not found"

Answer (score 1):

If the loop body uses names from packges, these either need to be declared [in the `.packages` argument to `foreach`](https://rdrr.io/cran/foreach/man/foreach.html), or you need to explicitly qualify the name use inside the loop body via `::`:

```
foreach (i = 1:7, .packages = 'hdf5r') %dopar% {
  data_i <- H5File$new(files[i],'r+')
  …
```

Or:

```
foreach (i = 1:7) %dopar% {
  data_i <- hdf5r::H5File$new(files[i],'r+')
  …
```

There’s no established consensus as to which of these is better. Personally, I prefer the second variant.